# Why is my Ember.Router giving this TypeError?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember built from git master. My RouteManager is not complex, but when I try to start my app, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '1' of object , is not a function

Following the trace indicates that this is happening on the app's initialization.

[This jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pjmorse/ubbcv/) shows the problem, although you'll have to look in the javascript console to see the error message. My actual router will be more complex than this, but I've pared it down to the bones to try to eliminate potential error sources.

Comment: I'm investing... for the moment, it seems that the problem at init time concerns the injections... the second one is undefined.

Comment: That sounds promising. I don't understand the injections or where they're coming from, so if they're under my control, I'm probably getting them wrong.

Comment: It seems that there is a mistake with your ember-data version. By removing data related stuff, and removing ember-data from resources, it works. see http://fiddle.jshell.net/f42UG/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update your version of Ember Data to the latest version from master, as the injection API changed.

Comment: Could you confirm it's this one ? https://github.com/emberjs/data/downloads It seems to be updated 5 months ago. So if this is a wrong version, how can we update from master ?

Comment: In my fiddle I was using one I built from source; I'll build a new one.

Comment: @sly7_7: Assuming you have a Ruby 1.9.x build on your dev machine (I'm using 1.9.3), you would check out the ember-data repository, then in terminal, enter that directory, `bundle install` to get the needed gems, then `bundle exec rake` to build. You'll find `ember-data.js` inside the `dist/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fiddle which "works".

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sly7/ZySzK/

I pick up an ember-data resource from another fiddle I found on stackoverflow.

The way of populating the arraycontroller is weird. Usually you pass the context in the connectOutlet method of the controller, by specifying a context (in your case, it should be Sylvius.Section.find() )
I don't know why, but doing this, I have the error 'Sylvius.Section has no method find'... perhaps an other mess due to ember-data/emberjs bad version.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for helping. I would not have thought to look at Ember Data for the solution.

Comment: Totally broken with the latest ember:
Uncaught TypeError: Object Ember.Application has no method 'registerInjection' ember-data-latest.js:4766
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Application initialize may only be called once ember-latest.js:52
Uncaught TypeError: Object Ember.Application has no method 'registerInjection' ember-data-latest.js:4766
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Application initialize may only be called once ember-latest.js:52